# `ERROR: cannot execute TRUNCATE TABLE in a read-only transaction` in Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am getting the `ERROR:  cannot execute TRUNCATE TABLE in a read-only transaction` in Heroku PostgreSQL. How could I fix it?

I am trying to `TRUNCATE` a table.

I am using the `Heroku Postgres`.

[image]

I have tried to figure out in the UI how I could change my permissions or something similar to be allowed to run not only the `read-only transactions`. But with no success.

Comment: You are probably connected to a standby server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, thank you for your time. Could you elaborate your point, please? I just have created a Heroku account myself...

Comment: I don't know about Heroku, and you may have to ask them, but unless `default_transaction_read_only` is `on`, these is the behavior of a streaming replication standby server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, how could I turn the `read-only` off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking at (Heroku Dataclips [docs here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips)) is intentionally made read-only. Its a reporting tool, not a database management tool. The express purpose is to allow surfacing data to a wider group of people associated with a project without the risk of someone accidentally (or otherwise) deleting or modifying data improperly. There is no way to make Dataclips read-write.

If you want full control to delete/modify data you'll need to use an appropriate interface, `psql` or pgAdmin if you prefer a GUI.

Comment: I'm using https://app.popsql.com/, but still seeing the same permission issue

Answer (score 6):

This is currently possible, you have to set the transaction to "READ WRITE" when creating a data clip. Here is an example:

```
begin;
set transaction read write;

Delete FROM mytable where id > 2130;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the error was solved by adding the following:

`begin; set transaction read write;`
(Without `COMMIT;`)
I don't get errors anymore, but I can't see my new table in the Schema Explorer. Do you know why?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).